# PHP return JSON to Ajax works on localhost only

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I've a simple contact form, and using Ajax to process it with a PHP file...

The problem is: it works just fine on the localhost, but it does NOT on the live server!, it gives me on the console:

```
[object Object]
parsererror
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

This is my code:

**PHP:**

```
if (isset($error) && !empty($error)) {
    exit(json_encode(["error" => $error]));
}
```

And

```
exit(json_encode(["success" => "success message"]));
```

**jQuery Ajax:**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "./includes/form-processor.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(data["error"]);
        console.log(data.error);
        if ('undefined' == data.error || data.error == null) {
            message_window.text(data["success"]);
        } else {
            message_window.text(data["error"]);
        }
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(jqXHR + "\n" + textStatus + "\n" + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

I've read a lot of similar questions here on stack overflow but most of the answers for them mentioned that it happens because they're parsing the data JSON by jQuery and return it from the back-end as JSON again!

So, actually that make me not sure if I'm returning it from the PHP file right or not!

I've tried to return it from the PHP this way:

```
exit(["success" => "success message"]);
```

And

```
exit("success" => "success message");
```

And

```
exit("success message");
```

But it doesn't work as well!

Also, as I said earlier

> it works just fine on the **localhost**, but it does NOT on the live server!

So, that sounds weird! o.O

What should I check to make it works on the live server?

Thanks

Comment: What does `console.log(data);` actually give you in your console? Do you have error reporting on?

Comment: `["success" => "success message"]` is a new array syntax introduced in PHP 5.4 so your production server is probably under 5.4. You should use `array("success"=>"success message")` instead

Comment: @Andrew you beat me to it, that is what I was going to suggest.

Comment: Do what @Andrew said, and make sure your PHP is sending it **as** json by directing the header before you return - `header("Content-Type: application/json");`

Comment: @Rasclatt , the `console.log(data)` on the **localhost** returns the `error message` for the form correctly, it's just a simple hint asking to fill the blank input.

Comment: Sorry I meant on the live, that is where the error is happening. What does it say there?

Comment: @Rasclatt , it gives the error on the question at the very top: `[object Object] parsererror SyntaxError....`

Comment: Sorry, just comment out the `dataType` and return the raw data so do `// dataType: 'json',` then see what `data` says. Also make sure you have `ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your php page so you can see what error(s), if any, are returned.

Comment: @Rasclatt , sure, after commenting the `dataType` it still returns the same error: `[object Object] parsererror SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data` ... and just to make you certain, this is how I'm returning from PHP now: `exit(json_encode(["success" => "success message"]));`

Comment: That is strange, shouldn't have returned an object but rather a json string. Did you already try using the word-version of array `exit(json_encode(array("success" => "success message")));`?

Comment: @Rasclatt , sorry, I wasn't! .... Yay! it works! ^_^

Comment: Thanks a lot @Andrew and you guys as well! I appreciate your help! :)

Comment: @Andrew , if you wanted to copy your comment as an answer and I choose it that would be cool! Thanks again.

Comment: @Homer sure thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`["success" => "success message"]` is a new array syntax introduced in PHP 5.4 so your production server is probably under 5.4. You should use `array("success"=>"success message")` instead. For your specific code, use:

```
exit(json_encode(array("success" => "success message")));
```

and

```
exit(json_encode(array("error" => $error)));
```

Comment: Thank you! that fixed it. Thanks again! :)